# MySQL Query for Epoch time to Human time

Tags: mysql, epoch

I've got a column populating from DoubleClick File Transfer as according to the DoubleClick documentation the epoch time being used in nanoseconds.

```
SELECT User_ID, Event_Time,
FROM_UNIXTIME('Event_Time') AS 'activity time'
FROM admin_datatransfer.activities;AMsySZb6L0gewyCQcBBJxolU2VIp
```

But for the Event_Time value of **1494194400061608** I get **1970-01-01 02:00:00.000000**

Does FROM_UNIXTIME by default use ns, ms, or s?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `Event_Time` in your call to `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Ad you can see it takes a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`as as parameter, which is documented in the same page

Comment: Getting a **null** value then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was the solution.

```
SELECT User_ID, Event_Time,
FROM_UNIXTIME(Event_Time/1000000, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x') AS 'activity time'
FROM admin_datatransfer.activities;
```

The result **null** indicates that the date is greater than the year 2038.